# How to block all connections from Europe on a TCPListener

Tags: c#, security, networking, geolocation, ip-geolocation

Is there a simple way using a TCPListener in C# to block all incoming connections from the European continent? I need to do the following in order to decide whether or not to block a connection:

1. Determine client's location (if in Europe, proceed to step 2, otherwise, bypass the security check)
2. Read authentication token from client (session ID). If session ID indicates that the customer is a citizen of a non-European country, authorize the connection. Otherwise, close the NetworkStream immediately.

Comment: Too much subversive content I guess ;)

Comment: The question isn't WHY I need to block content from europe, but HOW to do it. I have several good reasons to block content from European countries, but that's not the question.

Comment: IP blocking isn't necessarily going to block all european residents anyways. Someone from europe could easily use something similar to Tor, or another anonymizing proxy service anyways. To verify that they are a citizen, all they have to have done is connect to the service from a non-european country (granted, it's not the best way to verify someone, but it's the simplest for an alpha of a new P2P service)

Comment: Just keep in mind that a US Proxy will thwart that approach for people who really want to :) Same for some corporate networks.

Comment: No security (especially in geolocation) is ever perfect.

Comment: @Jason and IVlad - if you're from europe, I could see why you wouldn't like being blocked, but my company (located in the US) has specific needs to block connections from Europe.

Comment: @IDWMaster - Thwarting your efforts here will be trivial for anyone who wants to get to you, Europe or not.  You certainly will not be able to claim any kind of due diligence w.r.t any legal requirements by simply trying to block IP ranges.  That said, there are Geolocation/IP databases for sale out there, but they are for things like utilization tracking and probably disclaim any warranty of security.

Comment: The only LEGAL requirement is that I make an ATTEMPT to block European access to the service, it doesn't specify how well the attempt has to work. As long as I make an attempt, that should be sufficient, and will block MOST access attempts, because surprisingly few people in Europe know that such proxies exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try polling using a [C# GeoIP locator](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csharp) and doing a DNSBL list for your application (though I assume you're already doing such by asking this question).

Comment: This seems to work well on my development machine (virtual). It will be deployed to corporate after the legal department and the security department verify its usability as well as any legal or security complications that may result from its use (may take a few weeks). I'll post back here to let you know how it goes.

Comment: Also keep in mind that this is only one layer in multilayered identity verification

Comment: There will be numerous routines to effectively block all Europeans from accessing the service (including but not limited photo-identification procedures, similar to what other companies are already doing, such as Microsoft)

Answer (score 2):

You can check on an online database to check where the connection is comming from. [Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952268/how-to-block-all-connections-from-europe-on-a-tcplistener/4952309#4952309) has given an link to MaxMind's IP locator.

Comment: I can't accept his answer until '4 minutes' have passed. I'm waiting for that to complete.